# how to generate sound program for capctha in php

Tags: php

I am making API like recapctha.I am hanging to make coding for sounde system for this API.

What is the concept behind to make this code?
Id it possible to make this is javascript ?

Comment: Why can't you use recaptcha itself?

Comment: Although recaptcha is easy to implement, I personally from a client user perspective find them annoying.  Though as of recent they have improved.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the **PHP section** on [`http://captchas.net/`](http://captchas.net/). It doesn't seem like the ***best*** but it **does seem the best thing I can find on the web**, otherwise you'll have to **create it on your own.**

Answer (score 1):

You could have .wav files for every single letter and number, and append the - according to the captcha text - relevant files to each other and send it out to the browser as one big wav file.